# Keras get outputs for layers nested within another model (ie nested model layer outputs)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model looks like:

```
input_left = model.layers[0]
input_right = model.layers[1]
sub_model = model.layers[2]    # has 2 inputs and 2 outputs
loss_layer = model.layers[3]   # has 2 inputs and 1 output
```

I am able to get output of all layers using:

```
outputs = []
for i, _ in enumerate(layer._inbound_nodes):
        outputs.append(layer.get_output_at(i))
        # since my sub_model has multiple outputs
        # notion of sub_model.output does not make sense

get_all_layer_outputs = backend.function([*model.input, backend.learning_phase()],
                                         [*outputs])
output_of_all_layers = get_all_layer_outputs(x)
```

I have a model, say `sub_model`, nested within the current `model`, and so how do I get outputs of each layer within the `sub_model`?

What I tried:

```
for layer in sub_model.layers:
    outputs.append(layer)
```

Building a backend function with this, asks me to feed in another input (other than input_left, input_right). Even if feed it in, only that input will traverse `sub_model` layers and give me the output.

How do I get output of `sub_model` layers using model's actual inputs `input_left` and `input_right`, like how it would happen during fprop?